# The average order of the divisor functions ${\sigma _\alpha }(n)$, where $\alpha < 0$ (Apostol, Intro to Analytic Number Theory, p.61)

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, dirichlet-series

In Apostol’s book, Theorem 3.6 (p.61) states a result concerning the average order of ${\sigma _\alpha }(n)$, where  $\alpha  < 0$

I am including an outline of Apostol’s approach, I hope I have typeset it correctly!

In Apostol’s approach, the positive parameter $\beta$ is defined, where $\beta  =  - \alpha$

The result being proved is

$$\sum\limits_{n\, \le x}^{} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}} (n) = \,\,\varsigma (\beta  + 1)x + O({x^\delta }),\,\,\,\,\beta  \ne 1$$
$$\sum\limits_{n\, \le x}^{} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}} (n) = \,\,\varsigma (2)x + O(\log x),\,\,\,\,\beta  = 1$$
where $\delta  = \max \{ 0,1 - \beta \} $.

In his proof, Apostol applies the following asymptotic formulas:
$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{1}{n}} \,\, = \,\,\log x\,\, + \,\,\gamma \,\, + \,\,O\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right);$$
$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{1}{{{n^s}}}} \, = \frac{{{x^{1 - s}}}}{{1 - s}} + \varsigma (s) + O({x^{ - s}}),\,\,s > 0,\,\,s \ne 1\,;$$
$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {{n^\alpha }} \, = \frac{{{x^{\alpha  + 1}}}}{{\alpha  + 1}} + O({x^\alpha }),\,\,\alpha  \ge 0.$$

His approach is then as follows:

$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}(n) = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\sum\limits_{d|n} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}} } }  = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}} \sum\limits_{q \le x/d} 1 $$
$$ = \sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}\left\{ {\frac{x}{d} + O(1)} \right\}}  = x\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^{\beta  + 1}}}}}  + O\left( {\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}} } \right)$$
Apostol states that the last term is $O(\log x)$ if $\beta  = 1$ and $O\left( {{x^\delta }} \right)$ if $\beta  \ne 1$.

Once again, using asymptotic formula, Apostol concludes his proof by stating
$$x\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^{\beta  + 1}}}}}  = \frac{{{x^{1 - \beta }}}}{{1 - \beta }} + \varsigma (\beta  + 1)x + O\left( {{x^{ - \beta }}} \right) = \varsigma (\beta  + 1)x + O\left( {{x^{1 - \beta }}} \right)$$

When working through this theorem, I attempted to prove the result myself using the given asymptotic formula.  My working did not get to the result; I am just wondering where I may have gone wrong. It may indeed be one of those “tricks” to formulate $\sum\limits_{n \le x} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}(n)} $ in the “right” way so that key terms are not lost in big-oh representations, etc.

This is how I approached it:

$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}(n)} \,\, = \,\,\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\sum\limits_{q \le {\textstyle{x \over d}}} {{q^{- \beta }}} }  = \,\,\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\sum\limits_{q \le {\textstyle{x \over d}}} {\frac{1}{{{q^\beta }}}} } $$
$$\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\left\{ {\frac{{{{(x/d)}^{1 - \beta }}}}{{1 - \beta }} + \varsigma (\beta ) + O\left( {{{\left( {{\textstyle{x \over d}}} \right)}^{ - \beta }}} \right)} \right\}} $$
$$ = \frac{{{x^{1 - \beta }}}}{{1 - \beta }}\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^{1 - \beta }}}}}  + [x]\varsigma (\beta ) + \sum\limits_{d \le x} {O\left( {{{\left( {{\textstyle{d \over x}}} \right)}^\beta }} \right)} $$
$$ = \frac{{{x^{1 - \beta }}}}{{1 - \beta }}\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^{1 - \beta }}}}}  + [x]\varsigma (\beta ) + O\left( {\frac{1}{{{x^\beta }}}\sum\limits_{d \le x} {{d^\beta }} } \right)$$
$$ = \frac{{{x^{1 - \beta }}}}{{1 - \beta }}\sum\limits_{d \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^{1 - \beta }}}}}  + [x]\varsigma (\beta ) + O\left( {\frac{1}{{{x^\beta }}}\left\{ {\frac{{{x^{\beta  + 1}}}}{{\beta  + 1}} + O({x^\beta })} \right\}} \right)$$

The "${\frac{1}{{{d^{1 - \beta }}}}}$" on the left is problematic, because the asymptotic formula used depends on if $\beta  > 1$ or $\beta  < 1$.

At this point I ran out of steam and looked at Apostol’s approach.

But I am still intrigued… is my analysis incorrect, or is it just an alternative approach that ends up with a different, but ultimately unhelpful, result?

And are there any clues that would lead to breaking down of the initial expression like this:

$$\sum\limits_{n \le x} {{\sigma _{ - \beta }}(n) = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\sum\limits_{d|n} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}} } }  = \sum\limits_{n \le x} {\frac{1}{{{d^\beta }}}} \sum\limits_{q \le x/d} 1 $$

My first post, so I hope I have made myself clear and not violated any rules or contravened accepted formats and styles!

Thanks!

Comment: MathJax does not recognize `\(`, `\)`, `\[`, or `\]`. Use `$` and `$$` only.

Comment: Sorry, my first attempt. Fixing it now. Thanks